# Android application update issue in noughat

Tags: android, file, uri, updates, android-fileprovider

I was writing an app updater for my app. After that I make sure that I have my own old apk on the device,the updater worked very well till the **MARSH MELLOW** and when the **NOUGAT** person update it shows the error, this is what I do from within the app I'm trying to update:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(Update_App.this, getPackageName() + ".my.package.name.provider", new File(filepath));

}else {
            uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(filepath));
}
            intent.setDataAndType(uri,
                    "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
}
```

The app crashes when trying to open a file.

this is error log:

```
android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/.fTouch_app/Ftouch.jpg exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
```

Any idea to solve appreciate for help.

Comment: Are you sure that this error comes from this code? Your error is for a JPG; the code is using a MIME type for an APK.

Comment: yep it happens when update is done and click on installer this error is obtain.

Comment: i think the property is change in replacement of apk file from old apk in nougat,is it?